# Too much data in Database

Tags: android, database, image

I am writing application, where I store in Database Strings from Images Bitmaps. I decided to save String, not Uri cause I didn't want to expose that user delete image from gallery and there will be no access to this image from my app. And on emulator everything works fine, but now on real device I get  "Window is full: requested allocation ..." . I am depressed that whole program must be remodeled.. Please, help me solve it

Comment: **DEPRESSED** is making me feel tired

Comment: A bad design leads to a bad failure. Bloating a db with images is **never a good idea**.

Comment: Ok, I understood, but I'm just learning so it's normal that I make a mistake. I'm writting here cause I hope that somebody  gives me some adivce, so please don't be sapient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store large data such as image binaries in your database. `CursorWindow` doesn't handle large data very well, as you have observed.

Instead, store the images as files in your application-private directory (`context.getFilesDir()` for example), and store paths to the files in the database.

Comment: Thank you for quick advice, I'll try :) By the way, I read topic person which had similar problem with design like me, so I wish there were no such tips.